# npx create-react-app command does not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

[image]

`npx create-react-app my-app` command does not work.
**I had used all the commands available on StackOverflow. but I have not got any solution.**

Comment: In your screenshot it is installing right?

Comment: on your screen shot you show that it is working... what is the error message ?

Comment: Fix permissions for user has initial command `npx create-react-app appName`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine?

https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Answer (score 0):

You did

```
npx create-react-app .
```

The first parameter to the create-react-app script isn't the location to generate it in. It's the app name.


Please do

```
npx create-react-app <project name here>
```